# new Date() in MongoDB aggregate returns 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregate

I'm trying to see if a date is in the past in a Mongo aggregate pipeline, using Meteor / nodeJS. The pipeline has to be completely self-contained; I cannot pre-calculate any values.

The first step is to find the current date. According to [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/index.html), I expect new Date() to return the current date as an ISO date.

But what I'm getting is:

```
ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
```

Data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1
  }
]
```

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "now": new Date()
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "now": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

[Mongo playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O4j5FKCyOKS)

What am I doing wrong? How can I calculate the current date in my aggregate function? Many thanks for help.

Comment: Your syntax seems to be alright, I tested in my mongodb and new Date() returns the current data, it seems this is a problem in mongo playground

Comment: Does `Date.now()` exist as a function? If so, try `new Date(Date.now())`

Comment: Nice idea, but I get an error: https://mongoplayground.net/p/KoTG5dPbr-c